# Dodge 2006 Grand Caravan fuse F6

Tags: dodge, fuse, fuse-panel, grand-caravan

I have a 2006 Dodge Grand Caravan. I'm currently troubleshooting an issue with it not starting. As I was checking the fuses I came across fuse F6. According to the manual it is "12 Volt Out Ignition or Battery". There are 3 different positions it can be in. [This is the diagram](http://circuitswiring.com/circuit-diagrams/1/2011/10/dodge-caravan-2001.jpg) although it doesn't really show the 3 positions.

What's the deal with this fuse and where should it be? IGN, BAT or both?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure I'm following your diagram as per "F6" (unless you're specifying "Fuse 6"). I see the #6 position on the diagram, noting this is the underhood fuse block which has a lot of relays in it.With that in mind, I'm not sure I understand your question? Could you help us out a little with it and possibly post more of a question as to what exactly the issue is and what you're trying to resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the description a little wrong. Added how Chrysler describes the power outlet system with annotations in ().

> The power outlet on the instrument panel marked with
>   a battery receives battery voltage from a circuit breaker (PTC7 - Integrated circuit breaker) in the Integrated Power
>   Module (TIPM) at all times. The other power outlet on the instrument
>   panel marked with a key receives battery voltage only when the key is
>   in the on position (F5).
>
> The power outlet located in the center console receives battery
>   voltage all the time when positioned between the front seats (PTC7) and
>   key-on voltage when positioned between the rear seats (F6). The power
>   outlet located on the C-pillar receives battery voltage only when the
>   key is in the ON position (F6).

So in short the F6 fuse really only controls the floor outlet (rear position), floor console light and C-pillar power outlet's. My guess is that since the TIPM basically the same regardless of options, they deadhead the fuse in the middle. And if you do have the rear and floor power outlet's it should be positioned in the Ign slot.

Comment: See, that's what we keep you around for, Ben ... always pulling it out. Good deal :o)

Comment: Exactly it.  Even my new Pacifica has this movable fuse.  I've put mine in the battery position so I can leave something plugged in and charging while the car is off.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know what it means when it's in the "middle" position? That's where I found it. It's difficult to see on any diagram but there's 3 positions the fuse can be in. All the way to the left, all the way to the right and in the middle. In the middle is where I found it.

Comment: @Tobias See the update